# Combination of two columns as unique Key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Need to set a unique key by combining two column in mysql. For example

```
id Ticket_number Code     Name
1    5              123   a
2    5              89    b
3    2              89    a
4    8              123   c
```

Here I want to set the Ticket_number and Code as unique by combining both. i.e error should be occur only if the same combination occurs again. Ticket Number and code can be duplicated but the combination should not be duplicated. How is it possible. Please help me.

Here is the  create statement:

CREATE TABLE `arlog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ticket_Number` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Ticket_Number` (`Ticket_Number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: post your create statement ???

Comment: @Pankaj katiyar I have already created a table and I just want to make the columns as unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code to create table

```
CREATE TABLE ticket(
    id INT,
    ticket_number INT,
    code INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON ticket(id, ticket_number, code);
```

which will act as a composite key.

Comment: OP didn't ask for id to be included as part of the unique constraint.

Comment: oops...sorry...i thought it is the proper way...any way the id is primary, adding 2 fields with idwill do the same effect as on your question.. :)

Comment: @ Arun, I have created the table. I want to alter the columns with the unique key

Comment: @Pankajkatiyar, thank u for the edit. I misunderstud the question. Thought it ws for create a table..

Answer (score 5):

Create a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_table_ticket_code on table(ticket_number, code)
```

Answer (score 1):

follow as given

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
 id INT,   
 user_id INT,
 setting_id INT,
 NAME  VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON tablename(user_id, setting_id);

INSERT INTO tablename (NAME,user_id,setting_id) VALUES ('1',34,15)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME = '1', user_id = 34, setting_id = 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

`traffic_hit_reports` is a table name, 
 `ALTER TABLE` change the table schema,  
 `ADD UNIQUE` add the unique constraint and 
`content_id`,`hit_date` is a field name.

Now,

```
ALTER TABLE `traffic_hit_reports` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`content_id`,`hit_date`);
```

Result:
[image]